# Где ошибка?Маленькая программа на си.Построить матрицу инцидентности по заданной матрице смежности ориентированного графа

Tags: c, матрицы, графы

**Напишите программу вычисления матрицы инцидентности орграфа по заданной матрице смежности.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста, совсем запутался.Почему k (кол-во столбцов матрицы B) = 10 при выводе, хотя должно быть 6.Объясните, что я упустил.И как осуществить такой алгоритм.Порядок столбцов в выводимой матрице не важен, главное - что бы их содержание было верным.И вообще выводит не совсем то, что нужно...

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
     
    int main()
    {
        int i, j,  X, Y;
        int a[100][100], u;
        int kor[2];
    
        printf("Enter the dimension of the matrix X =");
        scanf_s("%d", &X);
        printf("Enter the dimension of the matrix Y =");
        scanf_s("%d", &Y);
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
            
                printf("a[%d][%d]= ", i + 1, j + 1);
                if ((scanf_s("%d", &u)) != 0)
     
                    a[i][j] = u;
                
            }
        printf("The entered array: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
                printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
     
    
        int k=0;
        int incidence[10][10] =
        {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };
     
     
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++){
    
            for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                if (a[i][j] = 1 ){
                    if (i==j){
                        incidence[i][k] =2;
                        k++;
                break;    
                }
                    else{
                        incidence[i][k]= -1;
                        incidence[j][k]= 1;
                        k++;
                    }  
                 
                }
    
            
            }
        }
        printf("The output array: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
                printf(" %5d ", incidence[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит так будто вы пытаетесь разбраться в чужом коде. Так?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy , если бы :) Я просто не понимаю, что я не так прописал в циклах.А картинка - в качестве примера ввода и вывода.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy ,может, поможете мне разобраться в проблеме, пожалуйста? )Если вам не составит труда, разумеется ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ошибка в строке:

```
if(a[i][j] = 1)
```

Эта условие будет всегда выполняться, так что я думаю тут нужно именно сравнивать `==`, а не присваивать `=`.

Так же я не разбираюсь в графах, но зачем вы используете оператор `break` когда `i == j`?

И так же небольшая помарка. Вы можете `k++` вынести за условия, т.к. в любом случае `k` увеличиться на единицу. И инициализировать статическую матрицу нулями можно в одной строчку: `int incidence[10][10]{ 0 };`

```
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] == 1) {
            if (i == j)
                incidence[i][k] = 2;
            else {
                incidence[i][k] = -1;
                incidence[j][k] = 1;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

[image: Вывод]

Comment: Cпасибо большое :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Матрица смежности квадратная NxN, поэтому ввод и использование двух размеров неверно
2. Матрица инцидентности объявлена 10x10, инициализирована как 5x5, а вообще её размер должен быть NxE, где E - число дуг, которое может достигать N^2 (если параллельных дуг нет), для его определения стоит посчитать единичка в матрице смежности (при вводе), или использовать vector, добавляя по столбцу

Если эти недочёты исправить - вдруг заработает?

Ага, Павел ещё if с `=` заметил